# Diffusion of particles

Tags: diffusion

If $n(\vec{r},t)$ is the number of particles per unit volume and $V$ the volume, then $N = nV $is the number of particles in volume $V$

For a small volume, it should be $dN = d(nV) = Vdn + ndV$

But the book says $dN = dndV$

I don't understand.

Also, why is $\frac{dN}{dt} = d\Phi$ and not $\Phi$ ?

Comment: What is $\Phi$?

Comment: flux,  $[\Phi] = [s^{-1}]$

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: Actually it's not a book it's a PDF written by the teacher. It can be found here: https://app.box.com/s/ef6meb6xa3nwiwtmbdt3 but it's written in french

Comment: @ACuriousMind So it is all okay. I removed my comment.